# powershell exchange question

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

First of all, I am pretty new to powershell, so my questions might not be framed correctly but what I need to do is this.

I have a requirement to disable an exchange user from changing his email password. I need to be able to do this using powershell scripts for now. This I will later have to implement via .net code. I am guessing that I will be sending powershell scripts itself via the code or perhaps calling the EWS api to do the same. I tried looking for help on EWS but couldnt find any on the job above.

Does anyone have any ideas how to accomplish what I need thru

[A.] powershell scripts

[B.] .Net code (with or without EWS)

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some references:

Introducing the Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.0
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

C#: Getting All Emails From Exchange using Exchange Web Services
http://omegacoder.com/?p=454

Using the EWS managed API via PowerShell http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2009/04/using-ews-managed-api-with-powershell.html